# Is it possible to reference 2 columns to the same table column in Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a table called `products` which represents products, every product has an ID.

I want to make another table called related_products which will be 2 product ids.

For this, I all the columns (2) to have a reference to the same table and the same column (products(id)).

Is there a way to do that? Because when I try I'm getting an error talking about the foreign key.

What I've tried so far is the following:

```
-- Products table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(
      id serial PRIMARY KEY,
      barcode NUMERIC,
      qr_code TEXT,
      photo_url TEXT[],
      manufacturer TEXT,
      is_active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
      creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
      last_changed_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

-- related_products table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS related_products(
      product_id INT REFERENCES products(id) NOT NULL,
      related_product_id INT REFERENCES products(id) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(product_id, related_product_id)
);
```

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: Relational databases allow you to have multiple relationships between every pair of tables. You usually define different columns as references for each of the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works after you fix all your typos:

1. the first CREATE TABLE is missing a closing `)`
2. there is a `;` missing between the statements
3. the second CREATE TABLE is missing a closing `)`
4. the column in the primary key of `related_products` are wrong. Should be `product_id` and `related_product_id`
5. the foreign key columns should not be defined as `serial` - only `integer`. You don't want FK values to be generated automatically.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(
      id serial PRIMARY KEY,
      barcode NUMERIC,
      qr_code TEXT,
      photo_url TEXT[],
      manufacturer TEXT,
      is_active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
      creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
      last_changed_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
); --<< this was missing 

-- related_products table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS related_products(
      product_id integer REFERENCES products(id) NOT NULL,
      related_product_id integer REFERENCES products(id) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(product_id, related_product_id)
--                ^           ^
--                wrong names here
); --<< this was missing
```

Comment: my bad I forgot to change it, I did change it in my query before posting, sorry for that, I'll edit my description.